# How can my Android app be optimized for different screen resolutions?

Tags: android, xml

i'm building my first app and i wanna make the app to be optimized for all screen resolutions. 
So, i'll tell you what i think i should do -in order to make my app work- with what i've found so far, but i don't feel like i've understand that despite some relevant posts that i read.

I've made the background image at 480 x 800 pixels for high resolution (hdp), 320x480 for medium res (mdp), 240x320 for low res (ldp) and 600x1024 for xhdp(??).
Then, if i put each one on the right folder in the "res" directory...for example "drawable-hdpi" for high resolution etc...will it work?

Are these the right dimensions?

Here is my Manifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.etking.winningnumbersgenerator"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="19" />

     <supports-screens
    android:smallScreens="true"
    android:normalScreens="true"
    android:largeScreens="true"        
    android:anyDensity="true" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.etking.winningnumbersgenerator.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
             >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

(Please notice the supports-screens)

And my activity_main.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.etking.winningnumbersgenerator.MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame" />
```

Is it correct the way i described above?
What do i need to do? Please help me with my first app!!!

P.S: If you need something else from the code,ask for it

## **EDIT: (Please read only below)**

I have read Android "Supporting Multiple Screens" but maybe was something i didn't get.
 I created a background image for each drawable folder: 240x320 in drawable-ldpi folder, 320x480 in drawable-mdpi, 480x800 in drawable-hdpi, 640x960 in drawable-xhdpi and 1200x1920 in drawable-xxhpdi.

The app **displays well** on the below screens (using emulator):

768x1280 xhdpi - 4.7'', | 
480x800 hdpi - 4.0'' , | 
240x432 ldpi - 3.4'' , | 
1080x1920 xxhdpi - 4.95'' (Nexus 5) and 
320x480 mdpi - 3.2''

It does **not look well** on:
 480x800 mdpi - 5.1'' and 1200x1920 xhdpi - 7'' as it has too much space in the middle down to the bottom of the image.

and also on
240x320 ldpi - 2.7'' the button nearest to the bottom is almost cropped as it is appeared down on the bottom of the screen.

Note that the background image displays well.
I've put layout_width="230dp" and layout_height="50dp" for the button.

Plase help me on this!

P.S: I'm not allowed to post images so you could understand better :(

Comment: Do you have an actual problem or are you just asking for the fun of it? Generally what you are doing is fine, but if you have a background that spans the whole screen it might sometimes be necessary to position and scale it manually on the screen.

Comment: I don't know how to make it work for all resolutions...
I wonder if it could work the way i mentioned. (Creating different images for each resolution and put them in the relevant folder, e.g drawable-hdp)
Please help!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Is it currently not working? If not then what's the problem? You have to explain what the specific problem is you are having otherwise we won't be able to help you. As I said above, what you are doing is fine in general. And the `<supports-screens>` tag in your manifest is not really needed. You only need to specify that if there is some density or screen size which your app does not support.

Comment: Sorry,the problem is that i can't try it in different device than mine.
I own a Moto G, so i use it to test my app...(the virtual Device NEVER loads) but it is completly sure that if i don't optimize the app for other resolutions,it will appear messy!
Also, i want to learn the right way now so i can be sure in the future about more "serious" apps i'm gonna build

Comment: Well you are going to have to test it eventually. I can just say it again: What you are doing is fine in general. You just have to be sure that the images are scaled correctly for each density otherwise they will be different sizes on different devices. You can find all the information you need [**here**](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

Comment: Thank you @XaverKapeller,please one last question: (as i wrote below)
I'm confused because while i'm editing the image in Photoshop and i transform the hdpi image to mdpi, from 480x800 to 320x480, the resolution remains the same e.g 150 pixels/inch. Does it matter? Do i have to change both dimensions & resolution? If yes, what's the right number for res?

Comment: No that does not matter at all. Just be sure you scaled the image to the correct size.

Comment: So, is this the correct size instead of the one i wrote?

xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Comment: dp = density independent pixels. 1dp always is the same size on any device with any density. They are used to specify sizes in the layout and have nothing to do with the dimensions of your image. Just test how big your images need to be. There is no one answer like "Your images need to be x pixels wide and y pixels tall".

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you read the [Developer Guide on developing your app to support multiple Screen Sizes](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). It will help you very well not just focusing on screen size, but also on screen DPI (Density per Inch)

Comment: Thank you,i've seen this.
I'm confused because while i'm editing the image in Photoshop and i set the hdpi image to mdpi, from 480x800 to 320x480, the resolution remains the same e.g 150 pixels/inch.
Does it matter? Do i have to change both dimensions & resolution? If yes, what's the right number for res?

Thanks for your time

Comment: See the EDIT of the post...
Anyone?

Comment: have you tried creating a small layout file? you can create a smaller layout file by creating a layout-small folder in your res directory and start creating a smaller layout for your app. This way, your app will support the screen size you want. Just make sure to set the preview size to the smaller ones so you could design well